# Qt save a QImage to a relative location

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QImage.save to save an image of my OpenGL framebuffer to disk.  If I just call save("plot.jpg"), I have no idea where the image ends up.  It's not in the application directory.  I can call save("/Users/wallacer/desktop/plot.jpg") to save the file on my desktop, but obviously that's no good for running on anyone else's machine.  Is there an environment variable or something I can use to save the QImage to a known location? Or is there a way I can just save the image to the directory the application resides in?

This seems obvious, but I can't seem to find anything about choosing a save location in the docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [QDir::homePath](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdir.html#homePath) or [QDir::home](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdir.html#home) to get a relative (and IIRC, platform independent) path.

ETA: Or the applcation's current path should be in [QDir::currentPath](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qdir.html#currentPath).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I feel dumb.  I'm just going to use a file dialog to allow the user to select a directory to save the image file in.